# Applying Excel sheet drop down list validations using Java (Apache poi API)?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've done coding for Excel sheet drop down list for a specific column but I want to apply validation.

For example - once the any value of drop down was selected in first row it'll not display in the second row.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried the developer guide? https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.